# Spring-Integration Simple Bridge with annotation

Tags: spring-integration

how can i define a simple bridge that just bridges from one directChannel to another with java annotations

in xml one can do it like this (taken from http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html)

```
<int:bridge input-channel="input" output-channel="output"/>
```

with annotations i would have expected the definition to look like something this

```
@Bean
@BridgeFrom("inboundChannel")
@BridgeTo("outboundChannel")
public MessageChannel bridge() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

but this gives me the error

```
IllegalArgumentException: '@BridgeFrom' is eligible only for 'MessageChannel' '@Bean' methods
```

any suggestions how i would translate the above xml-definition into a java-config-definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
@Bean
@BridgeTo("output")
public MessageChannel input() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

or

```
@Bean
@BridgeFrom("input")
public MessageChannel output() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Your work-around is ok, but a little less efficient.

**EDIT**

If you want to bridge two channels, the configuration for which you don't have control, or you want to bridge between "library" configs in different ways, this is a more efficient version of what you have...

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="inboundChannel")
public MessageHandler bridge() {
    BridgeHandler handler = new BridgeHandler();
    handler.setOutputChannelName("outboundChannel");
    return handler;
}
```

Note that the output channel goes on the handler, not the service activator annotation. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans) for this style of configuration.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i just don't want to annotate the intput/output channels because i want to activate different "bridging-components" between them depending on the spring-profile. e.g. a simple forwarding-bridge, a transformer, ...   that would be possible with the xml-defined bridge i guess

Comment: What I provided is an exact equivalent of the XML snippet - bridging from one channel to another.

Comment: not quite. with XML, i can define the input and output channels in the common configuration and the bridge in a <beans profile="x"> section. with annotations i will need to annotate the input/output channels directly and thereby cannot control how they get connected with a profile.

Comment: what if I'm using sprign cloud stream reactive and I want to bridge a channel to a  @StreamEmitter @Output(Processor.OUTPUT) ?

Comment: Your question is not clear; please ask a new question showing more information (rather than commenting on a year-old question).

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround using a @ServiceActivator, but i'm not sure if that is 100% equivalent.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundChannel", outputChannel = "outboundChannel")
public Message<?> bridge(Message<?> m) {
    return m;
}
```